# $.ajax request returns some error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

below ajax call throws error message. I can't figure out what is wrong. Thanks

```
    $('#filterform input:text[name=other_location]').bind('keyup', function() {
    var val =  $('#filterform input:text[name=other_location]').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://linkedin.com/ta/region?query='+val,
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            alert('success');
        },//success
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("XMLHttpRequest="+XMLHttpRequest.responseText       +"\ntextStatus="+textStatus+"\nerrorThrown="+errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Under no circumstance tell us *what* error you are getting! That would take away all the fun of guessing that software engineers are known to love so *very* well.

Comment: Perhaps the contents of the error message provide a clue what is wrong?  We cant help without more description of what you are trying to do and what, specifically, is going wrong.

Comment: well, there was no error, i whould post it if got :)

Answer (score 3):

What you need is JSONP

```
dataType: "jsonp"
```

Comment: For clarification, you need jsonp because you are making a cross site request (unless of course you really are working for linkedin).

Comment: It looks like you've left the site, but don't forget to mark this as the answer if it was.